# How to contributing python versions of tutorials? e.g. Tutorials for arm_navigation

Tags: ros, python, arm-navigation, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I sometimes find myself converting the C++ versions of the tutorials into python.

e.g. http://code.google.com/p/gt-ros-pkg/source/browse/trunk/hrl/advait_sandbox/arm_navigation_tutorials/src/arm_navigation_tutorials/

What, if any, would be a good way to add links to python sample code to the tutorials?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9293/how-to-contributing-python-versions-of-tutorials?-e.g.-tutorials-for-arm_navigation/) by [Advait Jain](https://answers.ros.org/users/219/advait-jain/) on ROS Answers with karma: 140 on 2011-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can think of two things you can do:

First, you can make a wiki page for your python tutorial. The general ROS tutorials simply put up two versions for the same tutorial:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials

For example,

- Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (Python)
- Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++)

Second, you can contact the stack maintainer, and maybe they'll include your tutorial package for release along with the rest of the stack.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2011-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1